# Displaying two arrays in one foreach loop

Tags: php, file, foreach

I am making use of two arrays in one foreach loop.
Here's the code snippet that i have written for two input file type arrays.

```
$file[]= $_FILES['f_name']['name'];

$tmp_name[]=$_FILES['f_name']['tmp_name'];

    foreach (array_combine($file, $tmp_name) as $code => $name) {
           print_r($code);
       print_r($name);
}
```

The resultant value i get on printing the array is this:

```
ArrayArray ( [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpC24D.tmp [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpC24E.tmp [2] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpC25F.tmp [3] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpC260.tmp [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => )
```

It prints only one array, doesn't prints the other array.
How can I get it printed?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the point in all that mess? Why assign new array and then combine it back? Any reason you can't use $_FILES already?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is printing 2 arrays, just the 1st one contains nothing.

`ArrayArray (`

I prefer to use `var_dump` compared to `print_r` as it gives you more details for debugging.

As you are combining the 2 arrays into one and they only have 1 index there is nothing in the `$code` variable, just `$name` - unless you add array indexes.

Comment: why wouldn't it print anything? When there are four files and all have the names.

Comment: Edited post - its because `$_FILES['f_name']['name']` and `$_FILES['f_name']['tmp_name']` are being combined into 1 list as values with no indexes.

Comment: can you write the snippet of the code using var_dump with indexes?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish/retrieve from the list? `var_dump` is merely a deeper form of `print_r` - replace `print_r` with `var_dump` to see what I mean

Comment: It looks as if you are splitting up the $_FILES array into 2 arrays then combining it back again... why not just loop on $_FILES array?

Comment: not exactly spliting. Because I am using input type files I am creating two arrays, One for file 'name' and other for file 'tmp_name'.

Comment: Right why not just `foreach ($_FILES as $file) { $name = $file['f_name']; $tmp_name = $file['f_name']['tmp_name']; }`